# Adding two Tensors with different ranks on TensorFlow

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow

I tried following on TensorFlow:

```
import tensorflow as tf

a = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([10,1]))
b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([10]) )
c = a + b

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
    print sess.run(c)
```

I expected an error like "Two Tensors must have the same rank." However, output was a 10-by-10 zero matrix. Why do you think this happened?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because of [broadcasting](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/0.6.0/api_docs/python/math_ops.html#add). You have one horizontal and one vertical vectors, once added they create a 10x10 matrix. The same applies for

```
import tensorflow as tf

a = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([10, 1]))
b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1, 10]) )
c = a + b

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
    print sess.run(c)
```

Comment: Same things apply for subtraction. Why there is no special NOTE for it in TensorFlow documentation.

Comment: substraction, multiplication, division - any element-wise operation broadcasts

Comment: and **there is** note. Look at the link provided "NOTE: Add supports broadcasting"

Comment: I meant to say there was no note for subtraction or other element-wise operations.

Comment: I guess docs are biased towards numpy users and this behavior will be unexpected for someone who hasn't used numpy. Improving docs could be worth an issue or pull request https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/new